# Earth engine - Converting Julian Date to Calendar date

Tags: google-earth-engine

I am trying to get a calendar date from two bands in an image that look like this:
[image]

The first band in the image is the Julian Date (an integer from 0 to 365), and the second band in the image is the year, which is a constant in this situation.

What I would like to do is tell EE, for each pixel in the image, take Julian date from first band and year from second band, and give me a third band in the date format DDD-yyyy.

Answer (score 0):

The format DDD-yyyy is not possible, since you can not save strings in image pixels. However DDDyyyy is possible and can be achieved something like this, where `im` is your image with the date bands:

```
doyyear = im.select("julianDate").multiply(10000).add(im.select("year")).rename("doyyear")

im = im.addBands(doyyear)
```